# How can I find active network interface from userland?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, ethernet, non-root-user

I know that I can find which network interface is currently being used by parsing the output of:

```
# ifconfig
```

or

```
# route
```

But how can I get this information as a non-root user? Is there a way I can build such a

```
$ magic-command
```

whose ouput would be `none` `lo` or `wlan0` or `eth0` depending on the device used.. or even `enp3s0f1` or `wlp2s0` on exotic systems, with no admin rights?

Comment: What do you mean by “which network interface”? What if there's more than one? Do you want the one with the default route if there is one? `ifconfig` and `route` don't require any privileges (at least not on Linux, which Unix variant are you using?).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ip addr | awk '/state UP/ {print $2}'
enp0s3:
```

This command was issued as a "regular" (non-`root`) user on:

```
uname -a
Linux centos 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If it is important to remove the trailing `:` from the interface name, use (for example):

```
ip addr | awk '/state UP/ {print $2}' | sed 's/.$//'
enp0s3
```